# create multiple servers in signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0, signalr-hub

I'm trying to learn signalR but I have a question. I couldn't find the exact answer. Below is my sample code.

suppose there are 2 occupational groups. Engineers and Architects.

I will email them a chat room link. but the link I will send to the architects is separate, the link I will send to the engineers is separate. they will be able to open their groups in the created hub. I know how to create groups etc.

my question is;

the link I will give to them is

/chat/engineers/guid?12345

/chat/architects/guid?asdf

Is it possible for me to create this through a single hub? If not, what scenario should I follow?

```
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMe", message);
        }
    }


   builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
   {
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builders =>
    {
        builders.WithOrigins("url")
        .AllowCredentials()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
   });

  app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

  app.MapControllers();

  app.MapHub<TestHub>("/TestHub");
```

Comment: is your goal to create two separate hubs. one for architects and one for engineers? Or are you simply wanting to use the same hub and then have groups in signalr ?

Comment: It seems you want to send to different group inside the same hub method, it's possible. You could send the group name when calling the TestHub  SendMessage method.

Comment: @mathis1337 it doesn't matter, I can use the same hub, I can create it in 2 separate hubs. my goal is to create 2 different pages for architects and engineers. For example, when engineer /signalR/engineers/guid=?allengineers enters the page for the first time, welcome to the engineer room will be shown, he/she will be able to create a room or enter the existing room. they will not be able to see the architects' rooms, if they go to the /signalR/architects/guid=?allarchitect page, they will see the rooms created by the architects.

Comment: @BrandoZhang not exactly. my comment above will be self explanatory.

Comment: It is very reasonable to do this. You would simple need to create a DB that keeps track of users, rooms, and the signalr connection id. So if a user creates a room, that would then be a group in signalr. If someone joins that room you take their connectionId and assign it to the signalr group id. As for the pages you simply create two pages to handle the only showing architect or only showing engineers.

Comment: @mathis1337 "If someone joins that room you take their connectionId and assign it to the signalr group id"  I did not fully understand. Could you please explain these steps in a little more detail? Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups This should help you. You are going to want to create groups for users to both Join and Leave. In your case you will have a Architect and Engineers groups. Then you will have rooms with a list of connectionIds so you can only send messages to appropriate rooms.

Comment: @mathis1337 have I got it right? I will create 2 pages.
On these pages, I will show the groups belonging to those occupational groups. (i will save the groups in db.) Engineer1, Engineer2 e.g....  I will only show these groups on the engineer page.
If the user creates a group, I will automatically create the name of the group as Enginner3, Enginner4...., if the group name includes "enginner", I will only show engineer groups on this page. (I will fetch the groups I saved to the db.)

Comment: I mean its a good place to start. From here I think you need to start writing some code and if you run into problems post the code here and we can work more off it.